# Network admin blocks P2P, Bitcoin clients can't connect

Tags: network, multibit

My university network admins seem to block P2P networks. So I can't download totally legit Linux distros via BitTorrent ;-)

Unfortunately, this also affects Bitcoin wallets such as MultiBit or Bitcoin Wallet on Android.

How can they block all the P2P while leaving other services working? How do I make the client connect?

Comment: Likely they use [DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection), and there is not much hope of trespassing it. I'd suggest buying some VPN account. Also, I hope you've read your university IT policy carefully and you are not violating anything by running bitcoin client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a proxy with `-proxy`, a VPN, or Tor.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why they invented Tor. If you use Firefox, there's an app called proxy switcher, that lets you run back and forth from your regular connection to the Tor network. It's not that difficult to install and configure. And even though Tor isn't perfect, it's great for this particular use.